# Duplicates of Stack Overflow posts that are on SuperUser

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flags, superuser

I have had a couple of occasions where I happen to run into duplicates of Stack Overflow posts on SuperUser, most of which happened to belong on SuperUser anyway, so I flag them on Stack Overflow.

When I try to paste the URL from SuperUser into the "As Duplicate" box, the system says the URL is invalid.  I end up pasting them in as an "Other" comment in the Flag for diamond box.

Is this the optimal way to flag these posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to close a question as a duplicate of something on another site. You can flag them to be migrated to the site they belong on and then flag it there to alert the moderators that it's a dupe that should be closed or merged, or you can just vote to close.

Some questions are also not worth migrating. The goal of migration is to find the best place for a question to get good answers. If the questions old, have been answered, or are of poor quality, it may be easier to just let them lie where they are. It may be worth closing them, but migration is not always necessary.

Comment: Okay. :)  The question (in question) was from the same poster and was identical (even in typos), so it was definitely a copy/paste job.  So, in that case would it be best just to flag it as off topic and let the mods attempt to migrate, or leave it as I had done it?

Comment: @jonsca For an identical question, I'd flag it saying the user cross-posted to another site and the question should be either closed or migrated and merged. The moderators can decide. :) Flag it and use the "other" textbox to explain what's going on and provide relevant links. There's no harm in just leaving it alone, though you can consider leaving a comment for the user saying that cross-posting is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

I usually flag them for moderator attention and I provide the link of the SU dupe.

Comment: Good to know.  I'm going to leave it open to get a few more ideas about it.  Thanks.